# c++ Bind wide string to sqlite3 prepared statement

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to bind wide string to sqlite3 prepared statement. I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316226/wide-string-sqlite-query-in-c) answer, but it didn't work

```
    const auto sql_command = L"SELECT * FROM register_names WHERE name is ?VVV";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3_prepare16(db, sql_command, -1, &statement, NULL);
    wstring p = ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer;
    sqlite3_bind_text16(statement, 1,  p.data(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    printf("sql command: %s\n", sqlite3_sql(statement));
    auto data = "Callback function called";
    char *zErrMsg = nullptr;

    auto rc = sqlite3_exec(db,  sqlite3_sql(statement), callback, (void *) data, &zErrMsg);
```

I tried using 0 or 1 in sqlite3_bind_text16 but I either get null or original string with no substitution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL statement, change `is` to `=`, and change `?VVV` to just `?`.

More importantly, per the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), `sqlite3_exec()` is not the correct way to execute a `sqlite3_stmt` you have prepared. You need to use `sqlite3_step()` (and `sqlite3_finalize()`) instead.

Try this:

```
const auto sql_command = u"SELECT * FROM register_names WHERE name = ?";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
auto rc = sqlite3_prepare16(db, sql_command, -1, &statement, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) ...

rc = sqlite3_bind_text16(statement, 1, ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer, ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) ...

printf("sql command: %s\n", sqlite3_sql(statement));

while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    // process row as needed using sqlite3_column_XXX() functions...
}

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) ...

rc = sqlite3_finalize(statement);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) ...
```

Comment: would prepared statement  be enough to prevent sql injection? or in c++ prepared statements are different?

Comment: @ntdllnewbie.dll "*would prepared statement be enough to prevent sql injection?*" - yes. That is one of the benefits of using prepared statements. Another is performance.