# How to read a UCS-2 file?

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, wofstream

I'm writing a program to get the infomation in *.rc file encoding in UCS-2 Little Endian.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  wstring csvLine(wstring sLine);
  wifstream fin("en.rc");
  wofstream fout("table.csv");
  wofstream fout_rm("temp.txt");
  wstring sLine;
  fout << "en\n";
  while(getline(fin,sLine)) {
    if (sLine.find(L"IDS") == -1)
      fout_rm << sLine << endl;
    else
      fout << csvLine(sLine);
  }
  fout << flush;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

The first line in "en.rc" is `#include <windows.h>` but `sLine` shows as below:

```
[0]     255 L'ÿ'
[1]     254 L'þ'
[2]     35  L'#'
[3]     0
[4]     105 L'i'
[5]     0
[6]     110 L'n'
[7]     0
[8]     99  L'c'
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

This program can work out correctly for UTF-8. How can I do it to UCS-2?

Comment: Your example code won't even compile since it's using a variable `fout_rm` which is not declared.

Comment: I missed the declaration line when I pasted it.the code has been updated

Comment: REad this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams

Comment: Incidentally, this code does *not* work for UTF-8 input (nor does similar code). You probably just got lucky because you only used characters within the first 127 code points. C++ streams cannot decode different encodings, they are completely encoding-agnostic.

Comment: It looks like your "UCS-2 file" is actually a UTF-16 file with [a byte-order marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wide streams use a wide stream buffer to access the file. The Wide stream buffer reads bytes from the file and uses its codecvt facet to convert these bytes to wide characters. The default codecvt facet is `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char ,std::mbstate_t>` which converts between the native character sets for `wchar_t` and `char` (i.e., like `mbstowcs(`) does).

You're not using the native char character set, so what you want is a codecvt facet that reads `UCS-2` as a multibyte sequence and converts it to wide characters.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wifstream fin("en.rc", std::ios::binary); // You need to open the file in binary mode

    // Imbue the file stream with a codecvt facet that uses UTF-16 as the external multibyte encoding
    fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(),
              new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0xffff, consume_header>));

    // ^ We set 0xFFFF as the maxcode because that's the largest that will fit in a single wchar_t
    //   We use consume_header to detect and use the UTF-16 'BOM'

    // The following is not really the correct way to write Unicode output, but it's easy
    std::wstring sLine;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    while (getline(fin, sLine))
    {
        std::cout << convert.to_bytes(sLine) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note that there's an issue with `UTF-16` here. The purpose of `wchar_t` is for one `wchar_t` to represent one codepoint. However Windows uses `UTF-16` which represents some codepoints as *two* `wchar_t`s. This means that the standard API doesn't work very well with Windows.

The consequence here is that when the file contains a surrogate pair, `codecvt_utf16` will read that pair, convert it to a single codepoint value greater than 16 bits and have to truncate the value to 16 bits to stick it in a `wchar_t`. This means this code really is limited to `UCS-2`. I've set the maxcode template parameter to `0xFFFF` to reflect this.

There are a number of other problems with `wchar_t`, and you might want to just avoid it entirely: [What's “wrong” with C++ wchar_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107667/365496)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

    FILE* f = _wfopen(L"myfile.txt", L"rb");
    auto file_size = fs::file_size(filename);
std::wstring buf;       
buf.resize((size_t)file_size / sizeof(decltype(buf)::value_type));// buf in my code is a template object, so I use decltype(buf) to decide its type.
    fread(&buf[0], 1, 2, f); // escape UCS2 BOM
    fread(&buf[0], 1, file_size, f);
```