# Remove ÿþ from string

Tags: php, id3

I'm trying to read ID3 data in bulk. On some of the tracks, ÿþ appears. I can remove the first 2 characters, but that hurts the tracks that don't have it.

This is what I currently have:

```
$trackartist=str_replace("\0", "", $trackartist1);
```

Any suggestions would be greatful, thanks!

Comment: Does `str_replace("ÿþ", "", $trackartist1);` work?

Comment: No, it does not. @Carpetsmoker

Comment: Can you provide a sample string of ID3 data?  str_replace supports multibyte strings, and @Carpetsmoker's suggestion seems to work: http://codepad.org/Od59V0ki

Comment: Why doesn't @Carpetsmoker suggestion work?  That would seem to be the answer here.  To go further you can add an IF statement around that str_replace to see if starts with "ÿþ" first.

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump()` of your string to see what it contains exactly?

Comment: IF I use `$tracktitle=str_replace("ÿþ", "", $tracktitle1);` It doesn't work, but if I use `$tracktitle=str_replace("ÿþ", "", "ÿþChange The Way");` it does work

Comment: @Carpetsmoker This is the var_dump for one `ÿþA&#0;m&#0;o&#0;n&#0;g&#0; &#0;T&#0;h&#0;e&#0; &#0;T&#0;h&#0;i&#0;r&#0;s&#0;t&#0;y&#0;`

Comment: You should solve this from the root. This mark is the UCS2 file BOM, escape them when read a UCS2 file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643500/how-to-read-a-ucs-2-file/64983143#64983143

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ÿþ` is 0xfffe in UTF-8; this is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) in UTF-16.
You can convert your string to UTF-8 with [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$trackartist1 = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $trackartist1);

# Same as above, but different extension
$trackartist1 = mb_convert_encoding($trackartist1, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');

# str_replace() should now work
$trackartist1 = str_replace('ÿþ', '', $trackartist1);
```

This assumes `$trackartist1` is always in UTF-16LE; check the documentation of your ID3 tag library on how to get the encoding of the tags, since this may be different for different files. You usually want to convert everything to UTF-8, since this is what PHP uses by default.

Comment: When I use `$trackartist1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $trackartist1);` and `str_replace('ÿþ', '', $trackartist1);` it then switches to þÿ at the beginning

Comment: Second one should be `mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE')`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but was not able to force `UTF-16LE` as the input charset could change. Finally I [detect `UTF-8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407996/318765) as follows:

```
if (!preg_match('~~u', $html)) {
```

For the case that this fails I [obtain the correct encoding through the BOM](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#91051):

```
function detect_bom_encoding($str) {
    if ($str[0] == chr(0xEF) && $str[1] == chr(0xBB) && $str[2] == chr(0xBF)) {
        return 'UTF-8';
    }
    else if ($str[0] == chr(0x00) && $str[1] == chr(0x00) && $str[2] == chr(0xFE) && $str[3] == chr(0xFF)) {
        return 'UTF-32BE';
    }
    else if ($str[0] == chr(0xFF) && $str[1] == chr(0xFE)) {
        if ($str[2] == chr(0x00) && $str[3] == chr(0x00)) {
            return 'UTF-32LE';
        }
        return 'UTF-16LE';
    }
    else if ($str[0] == chr(0xFE) && $str[1] == chr(0xFF)) {
        return 'UTF-16BE';
    }
}
```

And now I'm able to use `iconv()` as you can see in [@carpetsmoker answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26493475/318765):

```
iconv(detect_bom_encoding($html), 'UTF-8', $html);
```

I did not use `mb_convert_encoding()` as it did not remove the BOM (and did not convert the linebreaks as `iconv()` does):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replacement:

```
$trackartist1 = preg_replace("/\x00?/", "", $trackartist1);
```

The regex above seeks the first occurrence of "\x00"(hexadecimal zeros), if possible, and replaces it with nothing.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker my bad! I thought he wants to get `\0` characters out as mentioned in his code. I didn't notice `\xfffe`.