# While reading from file in java, input is prefixed by two junk characters

Tags: java, file, utf-8

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\testout.txt");    
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);    
int i;    
while((i = bin.read())!=-1) {    
    System.out.print((char)i);    
}    

bin.close();    
fin.close();
```

output: `ÿþGreat`

I have checked the file testout.txt, it contains only one word i.e, `Great`.

Comment: output is coming with two additional characters->>    ÿþGreat.

Comment: Can you provide an input/output example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

When you're using text, you should use a Reader. eg.

```
try(
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
        Paths.get("D:\\testout.txt"), 
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    ){
    int i;    
    while((i = reader.read())!=-1) {    
        System.out.print((char)i);    
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), optional but allowed in files using UTF-8 character encoding. Some programs (e.g. Notepad) account for this possibility, some don't. Java by default doesn't strip them.

One utility to solve this is the [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) from Apache Commons IO.

Also, Notepad will write the byte order mark in the file when you save it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

ÿþ is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) in UTF-16. You can convert your string to UTF-8 with java.io as explained [here](http://www.novixys.com/blog/convert-utf-16-text-file-utf-8-java/).

You may also refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26493475/2465608) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Please use utf-8 Characters encoding for resolving this kind of issue.
byte[] utf_8 = input.getBytes("UTF-8");  // convert unicode string to UTF-8
String test = new String(utf_8);