# Removing printing characters from a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, text-processing

I am trying to removing some strange printing characters that are in several files, the contents of these files have been pulled into a PHP string.

I have tried using `preg_replace` to remove the strange printing characters, but haven't had much success.

The strange part is the regex I used with `preg_replace` does seem to work when I test it using a web based regex tester, so am confused as to why it doesn't work when I have the same regex in my PHP file.

The input data is just over 2000 lines, below is a snippet of the input data showing the `þ` which is what I am wanting to remove along with the `$NoCode`

```
$800C5304 0063
$800C5306 0063
$800C5308 0063
$800C530A 0063
$800C530C 0063
$800C530E 0063
$800C5310 0063
$800C5312 0063
$800C5314 0063
$800C5316 0063
$800C5318 0063
$800C531A 0063
$800C531C 0063
þ
$NoCode
```

This is the regex I have tried with `preg_replace`

```
$fileData = preg_replace("/\$([A-F0-9]+) ([A-F0-9]+)\n(.+)\n\$NoCode/", "'\$$1 $2'", $fileData);
```

From the link below, the `þ` seems to be or at least part of a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) in UTF-16.

[Remove ÿþ from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493053/remove-%C3%BF%C3%BE-from-string)

When I run `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($fileData), 'UTF-8', $fileData);` I get:

> `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`.

If I do `iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $fileData)` instead I get:

> `iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input`

Comment: "when I test it using a web based regex tester" it works (see: https://regex101.com/r/D2e1Wn/1)  But what are the results when not using a web based regex tester?

Comment: @Luuk the output is the same as the input, the data doesn't change. Also as mentioned in my question I too found that it works but it doesn't in my PHP for some reason.

Comment: @anubhava because I want to replace just that part of the file and not have it replace something else which I don't want it to.

Comment: please show output of `var_dump($input);` in your question

Comment: Maybe you could just use str_replace $fileData = str_replace(['þ','$NoCode'], '', $fileData);

Comment: @KazimierzNiewielki I did try `$fileData = str_replace('þ', '', $fileData)` without the square brackets, but that didn't work either. Also not sure what the square brackets mean.

Comment: @AeroMaxx square brackets mean an array. From manual: If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search. That is wierd because that should work and works when I try it on input text you provided. Can you show us all your code and input.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems the `þ` was an incomplete multibyte string. I fixed this using the command below to remove the incomplete multibyte strings.

`$fileData = mb_convert_encoding($fileData, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');`

This left a `?` where the `þ` originally was, I then removed this using the following.

`$fileData = str_replace("\n?\n\$NoCode", '', $fileData);`

Answer (score 0):

str_replace should be faster than preg_replace
Here is an example:

```
$input = file_get_contents('input.txt');
$output = str_replace(['þ','$NoCode'], '', $input);
file_put_contents('output.txt', $output);
```

Or if you want get rid of empty lines too:

```
$input = file_get_contents('input.txt');
$output = str_replace(["þ\r\n","\$NoCode\r\n", "þ\n","\$NoCode\n", "þ\r", "\$NoCode\r"], '', $input);
file_put_contents('output.txt', $output);
```