# Getting garbage when using getline()

Tags: c++, io, getline

I am practicing classes and I am trying to allow the user to enter its name using a space. When the user enters a space, my output is "garbage". Is it possible to use the get.line function with a class? This is what I have.

```
//Practicing classes.

#include  <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


//Class decleration
class person
{
    //Access Specifier
    public: 
        string name;    //Member Vairable Decleration
        int number;     //Member Function Decleration
};

//Main function.
int main()
{
    //Object creation from class.
    person obj;

    //Get input Values for object Variables
    cout<<"Enter the Name: \n";
    cin>>obj.name;
    cin.getline(obj.name);

    cout<<"Enter the number:\n";
    cin>>obj.number;

    //Show the output
    cout<< obj.name <<": " << obj.number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? [I get compiler errors](http://ideone.com/3ACpIj).

Comment: If you have running code and want to know how to improve it (or check whether it's best practice), head over to [Code Review.SX](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have a problem with your code, add it in your post.

Comment: i just ran your code you need to remove **cin.getline(obj.name)**, after that the code will work

Comment: Yes the code compiles if i remove "cin.getline(obj.name);"

Comment: what are you trying to do though

Comment: Im trying to let the user enter their full name, for example "Chris Paz"

Comment: you cannot do it that way its either you put the name together **ChrisPaz** or **Chris_Paz**

Comment: So by "garbage" you mean a compiler error? If you get an error, you should post it and you should describe the behaviour you're encountering in detail.

Comment: Your comment for the `int number` method is wrong.  The `number` is a member not a function, just like the member above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
cin>>obj.name;
cin.getline(obj.name);
```

to:

```
std::getline (std::cin, obj.name);
```

as specified by the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). You can omit `std::`, since you are already using namespace std.

Example run:

```
Enter the Name: 
samaras
Enter the number:
1
samaras: 1
```

However notice that the data members of a class are usually on private scope and public functions can apply to them. Also, as Thomas Matthews put it: "This breaks data hiding and encapsulation rules. I highly recommend that the functionality for reading the data member be placed in the class.".

You may want to look into overloading operator `>>`. However, if you feel like you are not done with understanding the classes, I would suggest to leave that for later.

Comment: @Palermox But this code will read the entire line (a name and a number). You will have to parse the string to get the number's value.

Comment: Awesome, i got it. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: You are welcome @Palermox. If you want, accept the answer so that question appears as resolved.

Comment: This breaks data hiding and encapsulation rules.  I highly recommend that the functionality for reading the data member be placed in the class.

Comment: In my opinion, a better solution is to have the `Person` class overload `operator >>` to input the names.

Comment: I completely agree @ThomasMatthews, but the OP has a code with private data members, so he should study more to get to this point. However, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to return the full name of the user, So I create a simple function that returns a concatenated value using the first last name. but if you want you should go over **tuple or pair** to make advance function.

```
 #include  <iostream>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;
 class person
 {
    //Access Specifier
    public: 
    string firstname;
    string lastname;    //Member Vairable Decleration
    int number;     //Member Function Decleration
 };

string returnCompleteName(string firstname, string lastname)
  {
   return firstname + " " + lastname;
  }

 //Main function.
int main()
{
//Object creation from class.
person obj;

//Get input Values for object Variables
cout<<"Enter the FirstName: \n";
cin>>obj.firstname;

cout<<"Enter the LastName: \n";
cin>>obj.lastname;

cout<<"Enter`enter code here` the number:\n";
cin>>obj.number;

//Show the output
cout<< returnCompleteName(obj.firstname,obj.lastname) <<": " << obj.number << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem using the specified answers, because I didn't realize my file was encoded in UCS-2. This helped : [How to read a UCS-2 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643500/how-to-read-a-ucs-2-file)

> Wide streams use a wide stream buffer to access the file. The Wide
>   stream buffer reads bytes from the file and uses its codecvt facet to
>   convert these bytes to wide characters. The default codecvt facet is
>   std::codecvt which converts between the
>   native character sets for wchar_t and char (i.e., like mbstowcs()
>   does).
>
> You're not using the native char character set, so what you want is a
>   codecvt facet that reads UCS-2 as a multibyte sequence and converts it
>   to wide characters.
>
> ```
> #include <fstream>
> #include <string>
> #include <codecvt>
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     wifstream fin("en.rc", std::ios::binary); // You need to open the file in binary mode
>
>     // Imbue the file stream with a codecvt facet that uses UTF-16 as the external multibyte encoding
>     fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(),
>               new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0xffff, consume_header>));
>
>     // ^ We set 0xFFFF as the maxcode because that's the largest that will fit in a single wchar_t
>     //   We use consume_header to detect and use the UTF-16 'BOM'
>
>     // The following is not really the correct way to write Unicode output, but it's easy
>     std::wstring sLine;
>     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
>     while (getline(fin, sLine))
>     {
>         std::cout << convert.to_bytes(sLine) << '\n';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Include the relevant information from the link to answer the question on stackoverflow because links can become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file you are reading with an hex editor and check if there are some bytes before your visible data. I ended up by removing these bytes overwriting them with 20 hex data which means space, and then cleaning the file with the editor.