# Reading a UCS-2 file into a char array

Tags: c++, ucs2

In C++, is it possible to read a UCS-2 encoded file into a char array and after that covert it to wide string, or do I have to read it into wchar array in the first place?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["How to read a UCS-2 file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643500/how-to-read-a-ucs-2-file)

Comment: Nope.. my question is specifically about the scenario of trying to read it into a char array.

Comment: Yes, just open the file in binary mode.