# What exactly is the L prefix in C++?

Tags: c++, string, widestring

I understand what it does: specifies a string literal as a `const wchar_t *` (wide character string) instead of `const char *` (plain old characters), but how is it actually defined?

Is it a macro of some sort? Is it an operator for GCC compilers? What *is* it?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The literal prefixes are a part of the core language, much like the suffixes:

```
'a'    // type: char
L'a'   // type: wchar_t

"a"    // type: char[2]
L"a"   // type: wchar_t[2]
U"a"   // type: char32_t[2]

1      // type: int
1U     // type: unsigned int

0.5    // type: double
0.5f   // type: float
0.5L   // type: long double
```

Note that `wchar_t` has *nothing* to do with Unicode. Here is an [extended rant of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) on the topic.

Comment: Cheers, relating it to the float suffix got my head around it!

Comment: Here is [another good explanation on wchar_t vs Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107608/whats-wrong-with-c-wchar-t-and-wstrings-what-are-some-alternatives-to-wide).

Answer (score 21):

It's called an **encoding prefix**:

#### 2.14.5 String literals [lex.string]

> `string-literal`:
>      | `encoding-prefix`<sub>`opt`</sub>" `s-char-sequenceopt`"
>      | `encoding-prefix`<sub>`opt`</sub>R `raw-string`
>     `encoding-prefix`:
>        |  `u8`
>        |  `u`
>        |  `U`
>        |  `L`

and marks a wide string literal:

> 11) A string literal that begins with `L`, such as `L"asdf"`, is a wide
>   string literal. A wide string literal has type “array of `n` `const
>   wchar_t`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has
>   static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of L here is wide character: `wchar_t`. String with L is coded in 16bit rather than 8bit, take an example:

```
"A"    = 41
L"A"   = 00 41
```