# WinRT __FUNCTION__ undefined

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Phone 8 Solution with a Windows Runtime Component project. In the WinRT code I want to use `__FUNCTION__` for logging from a C++ class.
However, `__FUNCTION__` is not defined whereas `__LINE__` is.

Intellisense only suggests `__FUNCTIONW__` to use. But when I jump to the definition of `__FUNCTIONW__` in `crtdefs.h` I can see that `__FUNCTION__` is not defined there either:

[image: definition of __FUNCTIONW__ in crtdefs.h]

I have read [Why would __FUNCTION__ be undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482297) but that did not help me (or I did not understand the problem described there correctly)

How could `__FUNCTION__` not be defined? I thought it is build in to the compiler...

---

**Update:**

OK, I learned that `__FUNCTION__` is actually never colored. Yet I get an error when I type:

```
TCHAR* f = _T(__FUNCTION__);
```

It says:

```
Error: Identifier "L__FUNCTION__" is undefined
```

Maybe something is wrong with my UNICODE setup? Is there a special header that I need to include?

Comment: Have you tried telling the compiler to use C++11?  Or have you checked the MSDN site?

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is not a macro - so it's not defined in any header. `__FUNCTIONW__` is just a wide-string wrapper around `__FUNCTION__`. Oddly enough, in VS2013, intellisense doesn't recognize `__FUNCTION__` but it does recongnize `__LINE__`. At least with a standard Win32 project.

Comment: Windows Runtime uses C++/CX, it is not plain old C++, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine when I try it in a C++ Phone 8 app.  Do note that you might be confuzzled by `__FUNCTION__` not appearing in the IntelliSense auto-complete list.  You can only see `__FUNCTIONW__`.   Which is a flaw, the macro is [predefined in the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) but that was overlooked for the IS parser.  Since the definition of the macro doesn't appear anywhere in the included headers, the parser won't ever see a definition for it (like it does for `__FUNCTIONW__`) and you'll see it missing from the list.

I can't confirm if this is a known bug, the search function at connect.microsoft.com isn't good enough to filter the 6600 hits that match "function".  You can file the bug if you wish.

---

Update after edit: you are using the ancient TCHAR macros in your code.  There's a trick to get the correct macro but I'm not going to document it.  This all stopped being relevant well over 10 years ago when everybody stopped creating programs that could still run on one of the legacy Windows 9x versions.  Certainly entirely pointless on a phone.

You in fact *want* to use `__FUNCTIONW__` (without the `_T`), it produces the Unicode string for the function name.  It is a const wchar_t*.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. The missing coloring confused me. Knowing that, I guess my problem is actually somewhere else. When I do `TCHAR* f = _T(__FUNCTION__);` I get an error `Identifier L__FUNCTION__ is undefined` (I'll update the question to reflect that)

Comment: Yes, I am indeed porting some very old code to Windows Phone :-) I will rewrite it then. Thank you very much!