# visual c++ doesn't understand u'' and U'' literals

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use visual studio 2013. When I write this code

```
char16_t ch1 = u'q';
```

visual studio complains with Error: identifier "u" is undefined.
I thought VS 2013 should support c++11 standard and u'' identifier as well.

Comment: I don't think VS have complete C++ standard support ever. Try `L'q'`

Comment: `u` is for `unsigned` int/long etc. for character type, use `L'q'`

Comment: Please check the [support table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) before posting questions, no version of VS currently supports `char16_t` / `char32_t`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the information is readily available online.

Comment: No compiler currently supports C++11 completely.

Comment: Is there any special reason you need `char16_t` specifically rather than just `wchar_t`?

Comment: @Mario portability? :p

Comment: @jalf Last time I tried, my Linux system understood `wchar_t` and even Android does so (using some tricks). If you'd like to exchange files or strings over the net, you'll just have to ensure to use the proper encoding on both ends.

Comment: @user VS 2013 supports char16_t and char32_t types. If I write this

Comment: @user VS 2013 does support char16_t and char32_t types. If I write this

    char16_t ch1 = 105;
 
it woldn't be mistake. That's why I wondered why U'' literal is still unavailable.

Comment: @Dumas45 Both are marked as not supported in the table, they may have forgotten to update the table for `char16_t` after the last update, but either way unicode literals are quite obviously not supported.

Comment: use [`wchar_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/wchar_t), that's the C++ keyword and guaranteed to be available on all compilers that support Unicode. Also, [`L` prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087219/what-exactly-is-the-l-prefix-in-c) is much more common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Microsoft's Visual C++ 2013 supports [many C++11 features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist), the support still isn't complete.

As for [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx), they support only two (or three; depending on how you count) string literal prefixes so far:

- `L"Hello \"World\""` using `L`to mark wide character strings (i.e. `wchar_t` rather than `char`).
- `R"(Hello "World")"` using `R` to mark raw strings with special user defined delimiters (new to C++11).
- `LR"(Hello "World")"` using a combination of both.