# C++ Confusing Macros

Tags: c++

I was looking at some windows directx application code and saw that they use the macro _T(x) to set their window name, when looking at the macro definiton I saw this

```
#define _T(x)       __T(x)
```

then I followed and looked at __T

```
#define __T(x)      x
```

Why does this exist?

Comment: May have something to do with string conversions. Can you find an example where it's used? Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string is what I was thinking of, but it's a different case.

Comment: [Unicode Programming Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/unicode-programming-summary?view=vs-2019) `_T` is a macro that, depending on settings, may do something.

Comment: Used here:
 WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, _T("ImGui Example"), NULL };
or here:
HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, _T("Dear ImGui DirectX9 Example"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 1280, 800, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);

Comment: I guess DirectX once worked with MBCS and Unicode apps.  Thus `_T` was the macro used to denote a wide or narrow string depending on the build type.  Also, note that `GetModuleHandle` is also a macro -- it is actually either `GetModuleHandleA` or `GetModuleHandleW`, again depending on the build.  So it is in the same situation as `_T`, i.e. changing depending on the build type.

Comment: I know how it works with GetModuleHandle. When looking at the macro defintion of GetModuleHandle, it shows the two cases directly, while it didnt when looking at _T

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_T(x)` is usually a macro for a platform agnostic text character type. In some platforms it may resolve to just `x`. In others using wide characters it may resolve to `L ## x`, e.g. `_T("abc")` may resolve to either `"abc"`, or [`L"abc"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087219/what-exactly-is-the-l-prefix-in-c).

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted; it's the correct answer. You might also mention that it's a windowsism.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, regardless where I look its always the same definition though, guess I just didnt look deep enough, thanks!

Comment: @Noah It's possible that if you change some settings in your build environment, like support for unicode, you may say it defined differently.