# typecast structure member in C during assignment

Tags: c, structure

Is there a way to type cast structure member during its initiation, for instance:

```
struct abc {
    char k;
};
 
int main()
{
  struct abc data[] = {.k= 'TI'};
}
```

Above wouldn't work since k is of type char, is there way to type caste this member k (to int) during its assignment to 'TI' ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"type cast structure member*"? The member will always have a static type, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to change the type during runtime? This is not possible. Data types are determined during compilation.

Comment: What's `'TI'` supposed to be, a multi-byte character? Why would you want to assign that to an int?

Comment: @Lundin, yes 'TI' is multi-byte char, and if I assign it to char then it wouldn't work, so I was thinking if member K which of type char can be type caste to int to store this multibyte value.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want a `wchar_t` or an array of bytes?

Comment: If you want `k` be to an `int`, you need to define the structure in that way.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: Unclear. What value to do you want to assign to `k`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cast here.

```
struct abc {
    char k;
};
 
int main()
{
  struct abc data[] = {.k= 'TI'};
}
```

Your object `data` is an array of `struct abc`. The initializer is for a single object of type `struct abc`.

If you want `data` to be a 1-element array, you can do this:

```
  struct abc data[] = {{.k= 'TI'}};
```

or, if you want to be more explicit:

```
   struct abc data[] = {[0] = {.k = 'TI'}};
```

That's valid code, but it's likely to trigger a warning. `'TI'` is a multi-character constant, an odd feature of C that in my experience is used by accident more often than it's used deliberately. Its value is implementation-defined, and it's of type `int`.

Using gcc on my system, its value is `21577`, or `0x5449`, which happens to be `('T' << 8) + 'I'`.  Since `data[0].k` is a single byte, it can't hold that value. There's an implicit conversion from `int` to `char` that determines the value that will be stored (in this case, on my system, `73`, which happens to be `'I'`).

A cast (not a "type cast") converts a value from one type to another. It doesn't change the type of an object. `k` is of type `char`, and that's not going to change unless you modify its declaration. Maybe you want to have `struct abc { int k; };`?

I can't help more without knowing what you're trying to do. Why are you using a multi-character constant? Why is `k` of type `char`?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do to the value, it doesn't change the fact that the field cannot store that much information. You will need to change the type of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"...I was thinking if member K which of type char can be type caste to int ..."*

As mentioned in comments, struct members are `static` and cannot be cast.
But given your willingness to cast (even though that will not work) why not start with a type that naturally accommodates multi-byte characters, i.e. `wchar_t` ?

If this is acceptable for your work, then when working with `multi-byte char` in *`C`*, you can do the following:

```
#include <wchar.h>

struct abc {
    wchar_t k[2];//or k[3] depending on k will be used as a C string.
};
...
//inside function somewhere:
//assignment can be done as follows:
struct abc buf = {.k[0] = L'T', .k[1] = L'I'};
// Or:
struct abc buf = {.k = L"TI"};//Note, no null terminator, so not C string
```

Note: regarding 2nd method, by definition, `L"TI"` contains three characters, `T`, `I` and `\0`.  If `k` is to be used as a string, `k` must be defined with space for the null terminator: `wchar_t k[3];`.
([See examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087264/645128))

This results in the following:

[image]

(where `84` and `73` are the ASCII values for `T` and `I` respectively.)

Note: compiled using GNU GCC, set to follow C99 rules

Comment: ryyker, is this part of C++ only ?

Comment: @Milan - No, compiled its C using GNU GCC, set to follow C99 rules, but note the edit. Each multi-byte char needs its own space, so the struct member needed to be an array to accommodate `'TI'`

Answer (score 0):

1. `'TI'` is wrong you probably mean string `"TI"`
2. If typecast mean see the sting "TI" as integer you need to use union - it is called type punning.

```
typedef union 
{
    char k[2]; //I do not want to store null terminating character
    short int x;
}union_t;

int main(void)
{
    union_t u = {.k = "TI"};

    printf("u.k[0]=%c (0x%x), u.k[1]=%c (0x%x) u.x = %hd (0x%hx)\n", u.k[0], u.k[0], u.k[1], u.k[1], u.x, u.x);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EhbKG5qnW