# String types in C++: how to convert from LPWSTR to LPSTR?

Tags: c++, windows, string

I am calling a C++ method which returns `LPWSTR` (the string contains a filepath), but I need to convert this to a `LPSTR` to continue.

I never used C++ before and even though the different string types are explained in detail here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc, I got confused.

When I cast `LPWSTR` to `LPTSTR` (which should equal `LPSTR` in my app), I get exactly one Unicode Symbol. While I guess that casting isn't appropriate in this case, I don't understand why it returns only one character instead of interpreting all the 2-byte-characters of the `LPWSTR` somehow as 1-byte-characters. I found references to the `WideCharToMultiByte` function, which apparently can convert `LPWSTR` to `std::string`, which I in turn can not cast to `LPSTR` either.

So is there an somewhat easy way to obtain an `LPSTR` from the `LPWSTR`?

Comment: You don't need to cast, you need to make conversion. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx For your case, use CW2A

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447756/issue-in-converting-wchar-t-to-char) for sample conversion code. (The person has a question about the conversion result, but you should focus on the conversion itself.)

Comment: I tried assigning CW2A pszA(lpwstr) to my LPSTR variable, which works fine. However it doesn't compile since i try to return this variable as LPSTR at the end of my method. Can i return a value that i assigned, using CW2A?

Comment: be forewarned that unless you ensure that your narrow string is unicode (UTF-8) you could corrupt the contents by converting it.

Comment: CW2A creates a local variable. To return it from the function, you need to assign it to some other variable, for example, std::string, and make your function return type std::string. This is not related to conversion question. Or copy the string to caller-allocated buffer like `YourFunction(LPSTR buffer, size_t size);`

Answer (score 1):

Casting a pointer to another type of pointer will not alter or convert what the original pointer points at.

You should be able to call `c_str()` on a `std::string`, and cast that to `LPSTR`, I think. So, use `WideCharToMultiByte` (if it does indeed, as you say, convert to a `std::string`) and call `c_str` on the result. This will give you a constant string pointer (`LPCSTR`). You can copy it (eg via `strdup`) and cast the result to `LPSTR`.

The returned pointer will then refer to a character string allocated using `strdup`, so should be passed to `free` at some point when the string is no longer needed.

The `WideCharToMultiByte` function that I am familiar with from the Windows API (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx)) converts directly from a wide-character string to a multi-byte encoded string without going via `std::string`, although it still requires allocation of a buffer to hold the output string. You may be able to use it instead.

Comment: It tells me that a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPSTR", if i try this.

Comment: hm, this does compile and doesn't produce any Errors, but i still get only one character as Output (a pipe | for most paths that i enter). Why could i cast the copy produced by _strdup to LPSTR, when i couldn't cast the original string?

Comment: Because the `c_str` method retuns a `const`-qualified pointer, you cannot cast it directly to a non-`const` qualified pointer (which a `LPSTR` is). Creating a modifiable duplicate using `strdup` yields a non-`const` qualified pointer. Don't forget that you must `free` the duplicate at some point, i.e. you are responsible for memory management.

Comment: " but i still get only one character as Output" - how exactly are you observing this output? Is it possible you're displaying the pointer, and the not the character string that it points to?