# If we give a=123 1st byte of variable a having value 123 but if we give a=1234 then some other value coming

Tags: c, memory, int

When I am giving like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a =123;
    char *p =(char*)&a;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

I got output like

```
123
0
0
0
```

But we I gave like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a =1234;
    char *p =(char*)&a;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    ++p;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

I got output as

```
-46
4
0
0
```

I was confused in how the system stores the value (123/1234) in 4 bytes of variable a. 
if it less than 127 then 1st byte occupies the value as what we gave as input(i.w 123).

But if the value is greater than 127 then 1st and 2nd byte of variable a stores different value. Please explain how does it works?

Comment: How the values are stored is implementation-defined. Read up on "twos-complement" and "little-endian".

Comment: Related: [How are different types stored in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693685)

Comment: WP: [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) -- [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you store 1234 in an integer (4 bytes) it requires only two bytes to store 1234 since 1234 is less than 65535 so remaining two bytes are filled with 0. first byte prints -46 because it is dereferenced using a signed character pointer so it prints the signed value of data available in least significant byte in binary of 1234.

Binary of 1234 in 4 bytes will be like

```
0000 0000, 0000 0000, 0000 0100, 1101 0010
(byte 3)   (byte 2)   (byte 1)   (byte 0)
```

for byte 0, sign bit is set, so it's two's complement is taken and puts a negative sign which is nothing but -46

byte 1's decimal value is 4

byte 2 and byte 3 are remain unused for storing 1234 so it prints 0.

Comment: Note that `char` has implementation-defined signedness so it might be a positive number on some compilers. This is why `uint8_t` should be used instead of `char`.

Comment: uint8_t is typedef of unsigned char

Comment: @Lundin: You mean `unsigned char`, because `uint8_t` is an optional type for architectures with `CHAR_BIT == 8`... ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar No, I absolutely mean `uint8_t`. Portability to dysfunctional TI DSPs and other crap architectures shouldn't be anyone's concern.