# Wide character output result

Tags: c++, wchar

Why do I get numbers as output result when using wchar_t?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wchar_t q;
    q = 'A';
    cout << q;
    q = 'B';
    cout << q;
    q = 'C';
    cout << q;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::wcout` and wide literals.

Comment: With wcout << q; I do get ABC result

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the rules are, but `wchar_t` can be treated like an integer or something, so that's why you get numbers - because there's no `operator<<` for `wchar_t` with `std::ostream`, so it converts to an integer and uses that overload instead.

Comment: Anyway, Im new to C++ so even this is enough for me, for now :) thanks for the info :)

Comment: Be sure to use `L'A'` and `L"abc"` when using wide characters as well.

Comment: You should see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613494/why-was-wchar-t-invented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayed 'numbers' are the **value** of the character. That's the reason you get 'numbers'. If you want to display the characters you can use **[wcout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sda3xxca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` is a `basic_iostream<char>`. There is no `operator<<` overload for `wchar_t` for `basic_iostream<char>`. When you output `wchar_t` objects they must be converted to some type for which there is an `operator<<` overload. The selected conversion is to an integral type other than `char` and so the integral value is shown instead of the represented character.